# Create multiple subscriptions with for_each in terraform returns context deadline exceeded

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have created a module that creates a subscription and other resources via terraform.

As you can see it iterates over this two times. One time where env is "dev" and one time where env is "prod".

the problem is: It creates the subscription "-prod", but it will not create "-dev". The pipeline says "Error: context deadline exceeded" after 30 minutes.

In terraform plan it says that it is all good and it will add the subscription, but it will not do it.

```html
module "wmind_subscription" {
  source = "./subscription"

  for_each            = toset(["dev", "prod"])
  env                 = each.key
  name                = "wmind-it"
  management_group_id = module.wmind_management_group.management_group_id

  repo_name = module.wmind_github.repo_name

}
```

The terraform resource thats creates the subscription:

```html
resource "azurerm_subscription" "this" {
  subscription_name = "${var.name}-${var.env}"
  billing_scope_id  = data.azurerm_billing_mca_account_scope.this.id
}
```

full error message:

```html
╷
│ Error: creating new Subscription (Alias "***"): subscription.AliasClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded
│ 
│   with module.wmind_subscription["dev"].azurerm_subscription.this,
│   on subscription/subscription.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_subscription" "this":
│   10: resource "azurerm_subscription" "this" {
│ 
╵
```

hope someone can help me, thank you